# django model versioning/revisions/approval - how to allow user to edit own profile but keep old online until new approved?

Tags: django, django-models

I am building a site where users can make changes to their publicaly displayed profile. However I need all changes to be approved by an admin before going live. Until the changes are approved their old profile will be displayed. In the admin there should be a list of profiles awaiting approval. It is preferable, but not required, to keep a history of versions.

I have looked at django-reversion, but don't think that will handle showing an old version while keeping a new one under-approval.

I'm looking for ways to achieve this with django...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This apps do exactly what you need
http://github.com/dominno/django-moderation

Comment: It seems to be doing the trick, many thanks. I had a few problems setting it up - was getting an error saying the model I was setting up was 'already registered for moderation' - however some digging around proved this was something to do with a recursive include. Was fixed by moving the moderation.register calls out into their own moderation.py file, and then including that file.

Answer (score 3):

Two from-the-hip ideas. How about...

Use reversion and add logic which auto-marks a profile as 'unapproved' on save() if the save is not performed by an administrator, then add a custom accessor to your code that gets the latest approved profile from the reversion archive.

Or, if reversion won't play nicely, have a 'current profile' and 'pending profile' for each user and update the FKs when the profile is approved...

Comment: Thanks Steve. I went for the out-the-box solution with moderation as they described a use case that described exactly what I was doing 
"User change his profile, old profile data is visible on site. New data will be visible on site when moderator approves it."

I did see another solution - Django-Gatekeeper that looks very similar: http://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-gatekeeper 

Turns out reversion could be very useful to me also, to keep a history of changes to user's profiles. Anyone have experience with running django-reversion and django-moderation together?

Answer (score 1):

I've had some problems using django-moderation from dominno, which are:

- Using a unique model for tracking changes in several others, with a GenericForeignKey reduces the amount of tables needed to monitor things, but it's a pain to manage. And I don't trush GenericForeignKeys for this type of task.
- Deserialization of sandboxed values would invariably fail if I changed one field's name in the model. (for example, if I migrated a field change of name after monitoring it in moderation). It should at least be able to recover non bogus field values.

So I made my own app, which tackles the problems mentioned above.
It should give you what you're looking for.
https://github.com/artscoop/django-approval

It has auto approval mechanism, field selection (you can always ignore some fields, and put others to validation) and default values (for example, automatically set an object to hidden when it's created, so that it can be moderated without being visible in the first place)